# <div> and <p> disappearing from title in iOS mobile app

Tags: bug, ios-app

I was looking at the iOS Stack Exchange mobile app (version 1.6.6.2), and I noticed that the words `<div>` and `<p>` were gone from the title of one of the questions there:

[image]

Upon checking every other place I could find the title, (Mobile app inbox; Mobile app question; Desktop inbox; Desktop question) the title was

> How can i place <p> next to <div>?

rather than

> How can i place next to ?

I assume this is a bug, and that it is being treated as markup rather than a string.

Comment: Quick, someone edit a title to `<script>alert("pwned")</script>`.

Comment: From a quick search (I don't do iOS) it seems WebView (which I assume the app uses) doesn't natively display alerts. I wonder if you can put a minimized malicious script in the title though, that for example sends your auth token to another site.

Comment: If there's a security vulnerability in this, [check out this page](https://stackexchange.com/about/security).

Comment: Probably embedding `<textarea>` inside a title would look funny when viewed from the ios app

Comment: If that was really treated as code, there would probably be some new line inserted, except if there is a rule saying that p and div should be rendered as inline[-xxx], which I doubt.